# Rewrite url doesn't work when opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using a jS code to redirect all outbound links to the redirect page (which contains ads for me to monetize). It works quite well. But it doesn't work when the user chooses to open the link in a new tab.
Is there a way to fix it?

This is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://example.com"])').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if ($(target).attr('target') == "_blank") {
            window.open("http://example.com/redirect.html?url=" + $(target).attr('href'), '_blank');
        } else {
            window.location = "http://example.com/redirect.html?url=" + $(target).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to just go ahead and replace the actual link hrefs on page load, using a simple script like the one below. One added benefit of this is that it's a bit more honest/transparent to let the user know they're being redirected through a different site.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a:not([href*="https://example.com"])');

for (let link of links) {
  link.href = `https://example.com/?ref=${link.href}`
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a href="https://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
<a href="https://example.com">Internal</a>
```

Comment: I put your code in the <head> </head> tag and it doesn't work. Please guide me...

Comment: You’ll want to put this inside a script tag right before the closing body tag. Need to make sure all your links are rendered before you do this!

Comment: Yes, I did. Is there a way to encode the destination url ${link.href}